# Angular2: Form Build + asynchronous data loading

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have a form created using Form Builder (Angular2 Beta 1, TypoScript), i.e.: there’s something like this in `constructor`:

```
this.form = this._formBuilder.group({
    'username': ['', Validators.required],
    'email': ['', Validators.required]
});
```

The form shows up, everything is nice so far. What I *don’t* really get is how I handle the binding when I load the data (in this case: a User object) from a remote service (or some other asynchronous loading mechanism).

What I have tried, is:

- Load the data asynchronously in `constructor` or `ngOnInit`. Problem: Throws an exception, even before the loading starts (“Cannot read property 'validator' of undefined …”)
- Load the data asynchronously in `constructor` or `ngOnInit`, but before that create an empty form. Problem: validation does not work.
- What I would have expected to work: bind the form data to properties of a `User` object, and set properties of that object. Problem: no exception, but the data does not show up in the form.

I guess there must be some smarter/better way to get this working? I’m rather new to Angular2, so I hope the question is not too dumb …

---- Update ----

First, I forgot to mention that I use `ngFormModel` in the form – in case it’s important.

And @Thierry: I think that “temporary empty object to bind with the form” is what I tried to do (the 3rd approach mentioned above) but what didn’t work. Precisely, I tried this:

```
constructor(private _formBuilder:FormBuilder) {
    this.user = new User;
    this.user.username = 'abc';
    this.form = this._formBuilder.group({
        'username': [this.user.username, Validators.required],
    });
}
```

This displays the username, but it doesn’t even work when I move the line which sets `this.user.username` to the end of the constructor – which I find pretty surprising, as I would have expected data binding to take care of this.

Comment: Are you sure for the temporary empty object? ;-) See my plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/metUkOB7Sqfyr9DtCLR0?p=preview. The validation works even after the data loading...

Comment: Interesting. Maybe this is an issue of “Template Driven” vs “Model Driven” Ang2 forms. I use the latter approach and don’t have `[(ngModel)]` in the controls – could this be the reason it didn’t work here?

Comment: Yes I also use model driven approach. Without `ngModel` you need to set every control values by hand... It's not the case with `ngModel`: update the global object and every bound properties will be automatically updated ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can separate your username and email in Control object, than append it to form. You will have more control with that ( you can update it later ).

```
form: ControlGroup;
email: Control = new Control("");
name: Control = new Control("");
constructor(public fb: FormBuilder) {
 this.form = fb.group({
        email: this.email,
        name: this.name
    });

    setTimeout(() => {
        this.email.updateValue("invalid email");
        this.name.updateValue("Name");
    }, 3000);
}
```

[Plunker example](https://plnkr.co/edit/MkveCmYBfNtHm1TILj2M?p=preview)

Comment: Separating was the key. Thx.

Answer (score 6):

I see several solutions to this:

- Leverage an `*ngIf` to display the form only when the data are there
- Leverage the `@CanActivate` decorator (if you use routing) to display the component where the form is, only when data are there
- Use a temporary empty object to bind with the form. When the data are there, you can fill (or override) this object with the data received.

Here is a plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/metUkOB7Sqfyr9DtCLR0?p=preview.

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Answer (score 5):

You could also update individual controls in the FormGroup after data is loaded. For example:

```
this._http.get('/user/123')
    .map(response => response.json())
    .subscribe(user => {
        this.form.find('username').updateValue(user.username);
        this.form.find('email').updateValue(user.email);
    })
```

Important part is that you can find control instance in the formGroup one and update its value. Or simple

```
this.form.controls.username.updateValue(user.username)
```

would also work.

**UPD.** Note that in recent versions API has changed so you need to access `username` with getter:

```
this.form.get('username').setValue(user.username)
```

Comment: Am I to assume correctly that this will also update the value in the view?

Comment: Minor update, find was removed... it's now `this.form.get('username').setValue(user.username);`

Comment: the answer should be updated, form.find is removed

Answer (score 0):

use `this.form.setValues({username: this.user.username, mail: this.user.mail})`

Comment: Hi jfreire, and thanks for the answer! Your code might be correct, but with some context it would make a better answer; for example, you could explain how and why this proposed change would resolve the questioner's problem, perhaps including a link to the relevant documentation. That would make it more useful to them, and also more useful to other site readers who are looking for solutions to similar problems.